# C# abstract class return derived type enumerator

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

If I have an abstract class, is there any way I can return an enumerator of the derived class's type? Or would I have to use generics in the base class, or a generic method? Here's a really dumbed down example of what I'm trying to do -

```
public abstract class Person {
    public IEnumerable<MyType> Search() {
        DbDataReader reader = Database.Instance.ExecuteReader(sql);
        while(reader.Read()) {
            MyType row = new MyType();
            row.Load(reader);
            yeild return row;
        }
    }

    private Load(DbDataReader reader) {
        //load instance from reader row
    }

    //declare properties that can be searched, such as Location
}

public class Programmer : Person {
    //declare properties that can be searched, such as Language
}
```

Then somewhere else I'd like to be able to call

```
Programmer programmer = new Programmer();
programmer.Location = "My city";
programmer.Language = "C#";
foreach(Programmer programmer in programmer.Search())
{
    //display list of c# programmers in my city
}
```

I know I can do this with a generic method, like `Search<T>()`, but I'd like to be able to call the search function from a class that does not know exactly type the Person is (for example, a base class for an AJAX handler)

If this cannot be done, can anyone give me an example or reason why not? Or would it just be too hard to implement into the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search an approach with this "pretty" usage I propose an ExtensionMethod. With an Ext you don't have to define the effective type of the Entity twice. `programmer.Search<Programmer>()` => `programmer.Search()`

```
public static PersonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TType> Search<TType>(this TType row) : where TType : new(), Person 
    {
        DbDataReader reader = Database.Instance.ExecuteReader(sql);
        while(reader.Read()) {
            var row = new TType()
            row.Load(reader);
            yeild return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using C# 2.0. But for the benefit of users with similar questions that use C# 4.0 - Wouldn't this code reload the same instance from a different point in the DbDataReader? If I add `TType row = new TType()` to the top of the while loop, would this work?

Comment: I would add this line above the while (otherwise you create N-instances of `TType`). But it'll work.

Comment: Well I do need to make N instances of TType, as each instance will be returned in the IEnumerable<TType>. row.Load(reader) fills that instance of TType with copies of the data at the current position in the reader. calling row.Load(reader) again without creating a new instance will change re-load the same instance, and the IEnumerable will then contain N references to the same instance.

I don't use C# 4.0, so I can't test this, but would programmer.Search() not require the generic type in this example? I can't find this feature documented anywhere.

Comment: ah jea sorry. of course you need new Instances^^. But my Search needen't define the generic parameter in your code. The type inference can do this since C# 3.0  for you. Check: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/03/17/lambda-inference. You don't have to

Comment: Aha! Didn't realise that was possible. But in C# 2.0 it seems there is no way of using the derived type as the return type of a virtual method, without knowing what the derived type is when calling it. Shame really. I'll have to have a re-think. If I come up with a half decent solution for 2.0, I'll post an edit in the original question.

Comment: Isn't C# 3+ actually running on .Net 2.x? I guess you could actually run the code or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason you can't make your Search method generic:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Search<T>() where T : MyType, new() {
    DbDataReader reader = Database.Instance.ExecuteReader(sql);
    while(reader.Read()) {
        T row = new T();
        row.Load(reader);
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

and call `programmer.Search<Programmer>()`.

Where does `MyType` come from btw? Should that be `Person`?

Comment: but he wrote: I know I can do this with a generic method, like Search(), but I'd like to be able to call the search function from a class that does not know exactly type the Person is (for example, a base class for an AJAX handler)

Comment: True, there's something about this question that doesn't quite make sense; However, even if the object is a Programmer, `person.Search<Person>()` should still be valid, and return the same collection.

Comment: If I were to use Search<T>() as the method, then I would have to use Search<T>() where T : Person, new() in order to create the new instance. Search<Person> would therefore not be valid as it is an abstract class does not have the new() constructor.

Answer (score 3):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

> Covariance on virtual method return types is a fairly frequently requested feature, and I'd use it if I had it. It's never made the bar because (1) the CLR does not support it; we'd have to either generate lots of helper code behind the scenes to make it work, or convince the CLR team to change (the C++/CLI team did the former) (2) in most cases you can generate the necessary helper functions yourself quite easily; just make a "new" method that has the right return type that delegates its implementation to the virtual method, and (3) Anders does not consider it to be a particularly important feature. - Eric

So, No, it isn't possible, and YES, it's because it's too hard.

Answer (score 1):

@ben dotnet: the fact of not having to pass the effective type explicitely is not due to the fact that it's an extension method. It is due to the type inference mecanism and would occur as well on any kind of method (extension or regular).

In such a method prototype

```
public static IEnumerable<TType> Search<TType>(this TType row) : where TType : new(), Person
```

`TType` is known by the compiler to be the same the 4 times it occurs in the line. Thus, when calling the method it's enough to know the type of `programmer` to know that it will be the same type between the `<...>`. That's why we can omit it. It works also if there is no parameter prefixed with the `this` keyword.

Comment: i edited my post=) I know type inference and all the code-magic she does for us.

Comment: Ok Ben, sorry for this useless precisions about type inference. Hoping that at least one reader will take benefit from it to save me from having typed a totally superfluous speech ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic type in your base class and define your generic type in your derived class as the derived class.

```
public abstract class Person<T> where T : Person<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Search()
        {
            DbDataReader reader = Database.Instance.ExecuteReader(sql);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var row = new T();
                row.Load(reader);
                yield return row;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Load(DbDataReader reader){}
    }

    public class Programmer : Person<Programmer>{}
```

Comment: careful with this pattern. It may not do what you think it does. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx