# Abstract class and interface with the same generic method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, architecture

I'm writing two APIs that I will use with many of my projects. Some projects my use one of the APIs, some the other, but the majority of my projects will use both. I'm trying to design them as if they're completely separate, but I'm struggling on one thing.

```
namespace FirstApi {
    public abstract class MyBaseClass {
        //constructor, some methods and properties

        public IEnumerable<T> Search<T>() where T : MyBaseClass, new() {
            //search logic here. must use generics as I create new instances of T here
        }
    }
}


namespace SecondApi {
    public interface IMyInterface {
        //some property and method signatures

        IEnumerable<T> Search<T>() where T : IMyInterface, new();
    }
}

namespace MyProject {
    public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface {

    }
}
```

Both APIs require this search method. The second API has some functionality in other classes that calls `IMyInterface.Search<T>()`, and I would like those classes that inherit `MyBaseClass` to use the `Search<T>` function defined in `MyBaseClass`.

**Compilation error:** *The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'MyBaseClass.Search()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IMyInterface.Search()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.*

**Note:** When Search is called, T will always be the derived class of whichever abstract class or interface has been inherited. This was the only way I could find of achieving this in C# 2.0 ([C# abstract class return derived type enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096884)), and it's just caused more problems!

Is there a type-safe way that I can achieve this, without using objects and casting?

**Solution:**

Based on the accepted answer by Andras Zoltan, I created this class in my project, and will have to re-create this class for each project that uses both APIs.

```
public abstract class ApiAdapter<TAdapter> : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface where TAdapter: MyBaseClass, IJsonObject, new()
{
    IEnumerable<T> IJsonObject.Search<T>()
    {
        foreach (TAdapter row in base.Search<TAdapter>())
            yield return (T)(IMyInterface)row;
    }
}
```

I then inherit this class like so.

```
public class Client : ApiAdapter<Client> {
    //everything else can go here
}
```

Comment: Maybe its early in the morning and I haven't woken up yet, but I dont understand what the problem is. Why doesn't the code you've provided work?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post with the compiler error

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question either. Maybe providing a real-world example, as opposed to `IMyInterface` and `MyBaseClass` can help.

Comment: @Mongus Pong - Because the compiler is trying to implement the interface's Search method with the inherited Search method but it can't becasue the constraints don't match

Comment: @Andras, gottit I missed that.

Comment: @Connell - one thing - if `T` is always that of the derived type - then why pass it as a generic function parameter?  Surely `MyBaseClass` should be `MyBaseClass<T> where T: MyBaseClass`?

Comment: The solutions given here will work around your problem, but I think ultimately your problems started at the design phase and you would be well served stepping back a bit and rethinking your design so you don't have this problem.

Comment: What does `Search` search anyway?

Comment: @Connell Watkins - see my now undeleted and edited answer for a slightly different solution that perhaps also demonstrates why I think generic methods were not necessarily the best move.

Comment: @Jodrell - In my current project, MyBaseClass has a readonly property for TableName and has some setter properties which map to columns in a database, and the Search function creates an SQL query that searches an SQL database. This differs from project to project though. I've used very general class names such as `MyBaseCass` for this reason, and to help others with similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started my answer with exposition on why it's not working for you, but I think that's well understood now so I'll leave it out.

I've upvoted @IndigoDelta's answer but it highlights something I don't like about the overall design here - I have a sneaking suspicion you should actually be using a generic interface and generic class; not generic methods because it doesn't make any sense that:

> **Note**: When Search is called, T will always be the derived class of whichever abstract class or interface has been inherited.

I'm throwing this solution into the mix; which I think is better because it means that each derived type doesn't need to reimplement the `IMyInterface.Search` method, and it goes some way to actually enforcing this rule you mention.  It's a generic type dedicated to join the two APIs together, meaning the derived types don't need to do anything:

```
namespace MyProject
{
  using FirstApi;
  using SecondApi;

  public class SecondAPIAdapter<T2> : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
    where T2 : SecondAPIAdapter<T2>, new()
  {
    #region IMyInterface Members
    IEnumerable<T> IMyInterface.Search<T>()
    {
      return Search<T2>().Cast<T>();
    }
    #endregion
  }

  //now you simply derive from the APIAdapter class - passing
  //in your derived type as the generic parameter.
  public class MyDerivedClass : SecondAPIAdapter<MyDerivedClass>
  { }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the ideal solution! It also means I can keep the design of both APIs in tact. I'll go away and try this and get back to you.

Comment: I like this, its more elegant than the solution I posted and will prevent duplicated code.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly implement the interfaces Search method, e.g.

```
    public class MyDerivedClass : BasicTestApp.FirstApi.MyBaseClass, BasicTestApp.SecondApi.IMyInterface
    {
        IEnumerable<T> SecondApi.IMyInterface.Search<T>()
        {
            // do implementation
        }
    }
```

However, I think you are asking for the `MyBaseClass` Search method to be called when the part of the code that handles your object as `IMyInterface` calls the `Search<T>` method. I cannot see a way because you have two `T` types with different constraints that cannot be related. 
If you did `where T : BasicTestApp.FirstApi.MyBaseClass, IMyInterface, new();` in both definitions of the Search method then you would not have a problem but this would tie both your APIs together

Here is a possible implementation of your explicitly implemented interface method.  It doesn't avoid the cast but at least keeps it neat.

```
        IEnumerable<T> SecondApi.IMyInterface.Search<T>()
        {
            var results = base.Search<MyDerivedClass>();

            return results.Cast<T>();
        }
```

Comment: +1 This was the kind of thing I was going to go for - but I was trying to find a way of doing it without fixing the type - keeping it the same as the input type if possible.  Because it doesn't make sense for a generic function to *always* expect a type derived from its enclosing type.  That sounds like a generic class to me.

Comment: I think I like it +1 but, why not implement the interface on the base class?

Comment: @Jodrell I believe it's because FirstAPI doesn't know anything about SecondAPI

Comment: I've come up with a slightly different solution to this which uses a generic type instead.  Take a look - because what I don't like about this (cause by OPs design) is the need to close over the `Search<T>` parameter here

Comment: This works and is the 'correct' answer. The problem I have is that there could be any number of classes that implement both of these APIs. In one of my projects, I'm looking at around 60 different classes and putting the same explicit method in all of these classes seems to be replicating code a bit too much. I fear this may be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do explicit implementation of interface and when you will access methor thru IMyInterface.Search - compiler will run the right method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an explicit implementation.

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    // The base class implementation of Search inherited

    IEnumerable<T> IMyInterface.Search<T>()
    {
        // The interface implementation
        throw new NotImplementedException();

        // this would not work because base does not implement IMyInterface 
        return base.Search<T>();
    }     
}
```

Since the implementations are different this makes sense. If they are not different then either the base class should implement the interface and you should use covariance (.Net 4.0 only) to combine your contraints or, perhaps you don't need the interface at all.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not confused, could you not change your definitions, such that:

```
public interface IMyInterface<in T>
{
    //some property and method signatures

    IEnumerable<U> Search<U>() where U : T, new();
}
```

Providing a generic argument of `T` which can use to enforce that the implementation provides a search function constraint to types of `T`:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass : IMyInterface<MyBaseClass>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Search<T>() where T : MyBaseClass, new()
    {

    }
}
```

That way, your derived types are simply:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{

}
```

Which you can then do searches as:

```
var derived = new MyDerivedClass();
IMyInterface<MyDerivedClass> iface = impl;

var results = iface.Search<MyDerivedClass>();
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Would there be a a way round it by defining my second APIs interface as `interface IMyInterface<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>` and defining the derived classes like `MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface<MyDerivedClass>`?